# Is Theodore Levitt's concept of 'marketing myopia' flawed?

Tags: consumer-theory, corporate-finance, marketing

Theodore Levitt's article published in Harvard Business Review says that people do not want quarter-inch drills, they want quarter-inch holes. This line of thought probably emerges from a line of thought which is of the opinion that in order to thrive, a corporation should focus more on the customer's needs rather than the product itself, which is also the essence of the mentioned article. There is a lot of hype around this article which I find surprising, prompting me to ask a question.
Coming to the drill-hole example, it is indeed true that all people want are quarter-inch holes not drills by themselves, this sounds profound in the first instance. People want a solution ultimately, so if a new corporation designs something better than a drill say, a laser tool, then the drill corporation gets supplanted. So what Theodore would say is, the drill company should not be myopic about their role as a corporation, their goal is to create solutions for making holes and not drills so they should adapt to their customer needs. Ultimately, in doing so they lose their identity as a drill manufacturer, so what's exactly the hype about this article, is it just about how big corporations can avoid becoming obsolete by losing their identity ? I am asking is it that, in Theodore's view that the central essence of identity of a corporation is not it's product but merely it's name, as long as company X creates holes, no matter by what tool, it is not myopic ?

Comment: Hi! Having never heard of this example I enjoyed reading your question. I strikes that the anecdote is really weird, as I don't anyone who wanted a quarter-inch hole *as an end product*, rather than say a wall mount.

Comment: Having said that, I am not sure your question is on-topic here, as branding/non-quantitative marketing seems very opinion-based to me.

Comment: @Giskard baby steps, I guess. A hole is a "better" end product than a drill. It's worth noting sometimes people do want drills because they want to rotate things other than drill bits. Or maybe there are so many possible uses of holes that a company which tries to branch out into all the different uses of holes wastes its time compared to one that just focuses on holes.

Comment: see also "faster horses" - mind that people didn't want cars either, they wanted transportation, but people don't want transportation either, they want to choose their living environment independently of their work environment, but do they really want that? maybe they just want to live *at all* but the city council made all the living places far away from the working places.